# integer mp4 video in HTML metadata

Tags: html, discord, metadata

I'm coding my first HTML website, and I just tried to do something like [this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1091096575754911866/1151949455558447255/1694716552773129.png) with meta tag in my page's code.
here is the part of the code containing metadata:

```
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta property="twitter:title" content="HTML-tests">
        <meta property="twitter:description" content="Site de tests de Wishrito">
        <meta property="twitter:url" data-rh="true" content="https://wishrito.github.io/HTML-tests/src/vid/Maxwell.mp4"> <--- here is the video i tried to use in my metadata
        <meta property="twitter:image" content="https://wishrito.github.io/HTML-tests/src/img/Wishrito.png">
        <title>équipe HTML5 : news</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
    </head>
```

I used [Discord Embed Debugger](https://discord.com/developers/embeds) to check if metadata has been correctly sent, but as you can see on [this screen](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1091096575754911866/1151951500155818035/16947170391260098.png), there is no trace of my video in metadata. How can I fix this ?